# Joomla 2.5 form redirection error

Tags: php, forms, joomla

Here is my form

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=search')?>" method="get">            
<input id="search_key" name="searchword" type="text" class="inputbox" placeholder="Enter Keyword/Part Number..." autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" class="inputbutton" value="Search">
</form>
```

After entering any keyword say 'test', 
it redirects to **index.php?searchword=test**

But i need to redirect it to `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=search&searchword=test`

it is not working either in sef enabled/disabled

when i type `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=search&searchword=test` in url, i go to the desired page.

Please tell me where am i wrong

Answer (score 2):

Can you try changing:

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php')?>" method="get">
```

to

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php')?>" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mycomponent">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="search">
```